# One makefile for two compilers

Tags: c++, c, g++, cross-compiling, gnu-make

I have two makefiles, for native and cross compilation. The only difference between them is compiler name:

```
# makefile
CC = g++
...
```

```
# makefile-cc
CC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
...
```

To make native compilation, I execute `make`, to make cross-compilation, I execute `make -f makefile-cc`. I want to have one `makefile`, which should be executed using `make` for native compilation, and `make cross` for cross-compilation. What is correct syntax to do this, something like:

```
# makefile (C-like pseudo-code)
if cross
    CC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
else
    CC = g++
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can [assign/append variables for specific targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) by using the syntax *target:assignment* on a line. Here is an example:

```
native: CC=cc
native:
    echo $(CC)

cross: CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
cross:
    echo $(CC)
```

calling

```
make native
```

(or just `make`, here) prints

```
echo cc
cc
```

and calling

```
make cross
```

prints

```
echo arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

So you can use your usual compilation line with $(CC)

Answer (score 9):

You can pass parameters to make.
e.g. `make TARGET=native` and `make TARGET=cross` then use this

```
ifeq ($(TARGET),cross)
        CC = arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
else
        CC = g++
endif
```

Comment: As a side note, if this makefile is calling other child makefiles, you should export the CC variable.

Answer (score 0):

not exactly what you wanted but you can read `CC` as an environment variable. consider the following `Makefile`:

```
all:
        echo $(CC)
```

and you can call it with `CC=g++ make` which gives you:

```
echo g++
g++
```

or call it with `CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++ make` which gives you:

```
echo arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++
```

and the best part is you can put these in your `~/.bashrc` as `export CC=g++` and `export CC=arm-linux-gnueabihf-g++` respectively and do the calling with only `make`.

Comment: The usage of CC is good (although better would be CXX), but putting it in your .bashrc is a bit over the top. Just call `make CXX=...`, and don't speak of it again :)

Comment: @rubenvb `CXX` makes much more sense but I didn't want to change the variable in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it which is more portable than the gnu make `ifeq` way is this one:

`CROSS` contains either `arm-linux-gnueabihf-` or is empty.

```
CC=$(CROSS)g++
```

CC will contain the expansion result.