# Multiple compilers in one Makefile

Tags: makefile, cross-compiling

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13358273/2521423) here, which does exactly what I want. However, being new to makefiles, I am having a hard time seeing how to implement the second answer in my current setup.

I have a simple makefile for which I would like to use different compilers when compiling for Linux or cross-compiling for Windows. As presented, the file below works. To make for Linux I just type `make`, and for windows I type `make os=win`. In the interest of learning how makefiles work a little better, I would like to be able to implement the linked answer in the current Makefile so that I can make for windows just by typing `make win` or `make cross` as presented in the linked question.

Could someone help me understand how the structure presented in the linked answer could be implemented in the specific case I have here? Presumably there is a more elegant way than having `native:` and `cross:` targets and replicating almost the entirety of the code across both.

Any suggestions for cleaning up the Makefile in general are also welcome.

```
ifeq ($(os),win)
    CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
    OUT=cusum.exe
else
    CC=gcc
    OUT=cusum
endif

CFLAGS=-D_GNU_SOURCE -O3 -Wall -Wextra -lm --static
DEPS=bessel.h detector.h io.h stepfit.h lmmin_int64.h utils.h
ODIR=obj
_OBJ=main.o bessel.o detector.o io.o lmmin_int64.o stepfit.o utils.o
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
LIBS=-lm


$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    rm -f $(OUT) $(ODIR)/*.o *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to introduce an upper-level target.  Target-specific variables are inherited by their prerequisites, so you don't have to change all the targets.

However, you cannot update the content of targets or prerequisites using this method so you can't remove the assignment of `OUT`.  This means you can't get rid of the `OS` variable assignment.

One simple way to do it is to use recusive invocations of make.  Write your makefile normally:

```
O = o
E =
CC = gcc
OUT = cusum$E
CFLAGS = -D_GNU_SOURCE -O3 -Wall -Wextra -lm --static
DEPS = bessel.h detector.h io.h stepfit.h lmmin_int64.h utils.h
ODIR = obj
_OBJ = main.$O bessel.$O detector.$O io.$O lmmin_int64.$O stepfit.$O utils.$O
OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))
LIBS = -lm

$(ODIR)/%.$O: %.c $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

$(OUT): $(OBJ)
        $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        rm -rf $(OUT)* obj wobj *~ core $(INCDIR)/*~
```

Then add a target that recursively invokes make overriding the relevant variables (be sure to put it at the end or at least after the `$(OUT)` target):

```
win:
        $(MAKE) CC=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc E=.exe O=obj ODIR=wobj
```

Now you can run `make win` and it will recursively invoke `make` overriding the appropriate variables.

Comment: This works with some small tweaks, which I have made to your answer for your review. However, this breaks clean (or rather, clean only works on the native compilation, not for the win one). Could you suggest a tweak to get that working again, (something like `make win clean`)?

Comment: Do you need to have a separate clean rule for each target?  Why not just have the single clean rule clean out everything?